# How can I listen for clipboard pastes not targeted at my application?

Tags: java, clipboard

I'm developing an application which calculates and displays information which then needs to be copy and pasted into a proprietary program. To make this easier for the user, I'd like to enable them to <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, move cursor, <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, etc., and have my program pick up on the pastes and update the [Clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) automatically after every paste.

Is there any straightforward way of doing this? The only things I've found involve accessing DLLs and the like, and this isn't a project I can spend too much time on at the moment.

Comment: Why does it need to be updated after pasting? What should it be updated to?

Comment: The next piece of data. My program displays multiple values in each run, which are then moved into different cells of a table in a non-standard word processing program they use.

Comment: So every time they paste something, you want to change what is in the clipboard?

Comment: Yes. And when they're done they will close my program.

Comment: Sounds impossible to me, sorry.

Comment: Bummer. Not a big deal, but it would have been nice. I guess I'll implement a button they can click to copy the next piece of data.

Comment: What proprietary software is this?  And can it handle multiple "rows" of data at a time, like Excel?

Comment: It's a word processor with advanced features for Hebrew. The problem with the method you're suggesting is that the data won't always be pasted into empty cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, check this project out: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

That will allow you to listen to key events even when your app doesn't have focus. It won't work if they don't paste with a keyboard shortcut, though.